# Filter on empty string using ElasticSearch/Nest

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, nest

This may be a silly question, but how do I filter on an empty string in ElasticSearch using Nest.  Specifically, how do I recreate the following result:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/test/event/_search
{
    "filter" : { "term" : { "target" : "" }}
}
```

I've tried:

```
(f => f
    .Term("target", "")
);
```

which according to [ElasticSearch and Nest filtering does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540509/elasticsearch-and-nest-filtering-does-not-work) is treated like a conditionless query and returns everything, while adding a .Strict() throws a DslException:

```
(f => f
    .Strict().Term("target", "")
);
```

I've also tried .Missing() and .Exists() to no avail.

The relevant section of my _mapping for reference:

```
{
    "event": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "properties": {
            target": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "store": true,
                "omit_norms": true,
                "index_options": "docs"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Dont know why the src always throw DslException if Strict = true, but you can send the request `"filter" : { "term" : { "target" : "" }} `directly using QueryRaw/FilterRaw

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid that since it would take a sizeable refactor on my end.  I was hoping there was some magic I was missing.

Comment: I think you can post a bug to NEST to get helped. Maybe the author can suggest some better alternatives.

Comment: This is not a use case I envisioned but it's a really valid one. I'm working on adding `.Verbatim()` as a counter part to `.Strict()` which will not throw or remove the query if its conditionless but leave it as as defined. I will post an answer when its up on github.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the [documentation on NEST and writing queries](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/) mentions you can toggle `Strict()` mode to trigger exceptions if a part of your query turns out to be `conditionless` but if thats what you really wanted then you were stuck as you've found out.

I just committed a `.Verbatim()` construct which works exactly like `.Strict()` but instead of throwing an exception it will take the query as is and render it as specified.

```
(f => f
    .Verbatim()
    .Term("target", "")
);
```

Should thus disable the `conditionless` query rewrite and insert the query literally as specified.

This will make it in the next version of NEST (so after the current version of 0.12.0.0)

Answer (score 3):

I will just remark that you have to use Verbatim() on every query, not just once on the top.

```
var searchResults = this.Client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        //.Verbatim() // no, here won't work
        .Bool(b => b
            .Should(
                bs => bs.Match(p => p.Query("hello").Field("name").Verbatim()),
                bs => bs.Match(p => p.Query("world").Field("name").Verbatim())
            )
        )
    )
);
```