# Fuzzy Elastic Search Query in Nest with Conditional Filters

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am new to NESt and Elastic Search and while I was able to get a more basic query working, I am now attempting to tackle this one:

- Find a user on either the firstName or lastName field, for a given input *query* and it should be fuzzy so you can handle typos
- If city was provided, then filter any hits so they match on city
- If state was also provided, then filter any hits so they match on state
- Only include people whose field 'isSearchable' is true
- If a city AND state are provided then match on both of course

So as an example, I have 10 "John Smiths" in the index. If I leave out city/state, and just search on "john brown" as my term, or "john" or "brown" or "jhn brwn" I'd expect all 10 back.
If one of those John Browns lived in Flushing, New York, and another lived in Flushing, Georgia, and I put "Flushing" for the city, then I'd expect to get back both who live in Flushing.. If i put "Flushing" AND "New York" then I'd expect to get back exactly one of those.

I was attempting a few different things..Here is the construct I made. Keep in mind if I browse to the URL directly in Elastic Search and do a query for *, it returns my records, and if I do _search?q=somename it returns matches so I know i'm setup and indexed..

```
var foundUsers = new List<IndexedUser>();

 
                var filters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<IndexedUser>, QueryContainer>>();

                //If city was provided, then search on that
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
                    filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.City).Terms(city)));

                //If state was provided, then search on that
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
                    filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.State).Terms(state)));

                //Ony find users who want to be searched
                filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.IsSearchable).Strict(true)));
 
                var results = client.Search<IndexedUser>(x => x.Query(q => q
                 .Bool(
                         bq => bq
                           .Should(
                              s => s.Match(m => m.Query(term).Field(f => f.FirstName).Boost(1.1).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1))),
                              s => s.Match(m => m.Query(term).Field(f => f.LastName).Boost(1.1).Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(1)))
                             )
                           .Filter(filters))
                      ).Index("user")
                  );


 foundUsers = results.Documents.Concat(results.Documents).ToList();
```

When I run this, it crashes and gives an error:

```
2020-12-21T04:29:25.4214526+00:00 0HM55D28OUJ5C:00000009 [ERR] ERROR With Search: Query is conditionless but strict is turned on (47081e5a)
```

Which I understand above is likely because I have strict for the isSearchable, however I feel like I need some guidance here to get this right as I suspect I made a few other blunders.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Check this post: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364963/filter-on-empty-string-using-elasticsearch-nest)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks - so I'm getting no results - based on what I have above, does it appear to you that I am searching on two fields and both of them must satisfy a match? I was interested in finding a hit in EITHER of the above fields, but I fear I am saying it must satisfy BOTH firstName and LastName