# Conditional Elastic Search Filter for Fuzzy Search in NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a working query against my index however I am having difficulty getting a conditional filter working.

The query I have working is as follows:

```
       var firstSearchResponse = client.Search<IndexedUser>(s => s
            .Query(q =>
                (q
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.FirstName)
                    .Query(term)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                )
                ||
                q.Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.LastName)
                    .Query(term)
                    .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                ))
                &&
                (
                 q.Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.IsSearchable)
                    .Query("true")
                   
                 )
                )
            );
```

However now I would like to say that if a user passes in a city, or a state, or both, then filter on each of those fields to only return those results.

As an example, if I pass in a city of New York, then only filter those results.

How can I do this?

I tried using PostFilter but it doesn't seem to work when I pass in input:

```
var filters = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<IndexedUser>, QueryContainer>>();

                //If city was provided, then search on that
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
                    filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.City).Terms(city)));

                //If state was provided, then search on that
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
                    filters.Add(fq => fq.Terms(t => t.Field(f => f.State).Terms(state)));
```

and then at the end of my query, adding this:

```
 var firstSearchResponse = client.Search<IndexedUser>(s => s
                    .Query(q =>
                        (q
                        .Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.FirstName)
                            .Query(term)
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                        )
                        ||
                        q.Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.LastName)
                            .Query(term)
                            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.EditDistance(2))
                        ))
                        &&
                        (
                         q.Match(m => m
                            .Field(f => f.IsSearchable)
                            .Query("true")
                           
                         )
                        )
                    ).PostFilter(p => p.Bool(q => q.Filter(filters))));
```

..if I add the PostFilter, it works unless I actually pass in a value for city or state.
Am I misusing PostFilter, or is there a logic flaw above?

Thanks you so much for any help/guidance!

Comment: This looks like the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387601/fuzzy-elastic-search-query-in-nest-with-conditional-filters ?

Comment: I can see that - that was for the error I was getting, which is now resolved, but now that I've moved passed that, I am now stuck on something else